# Dias transcurridos entre fechas php

Tags: php, mysqli

hola amigos estoy programado un sistema en el cual me piden que muestre los dias transcurridos entre dos fechas con formato `Y-m-d` que seria la fecha actual - la fecha en que se ralizo el ingreso al la bd y me encontre con el problema que no me calcula los dias si solo las resto la actual - la de ingreso no me da nada ya he intentado de varias formas y nada

```
//primera forma
$datetime1 = date_create($fecha_actual);
$datetime2 = date_create($fecha_db);
$interval = date_diff($datetime1,$datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a dias');

// segunda forma
$today = new DateTime($fecha_actual);
$appt  = new DateTime($fecha_db);
echo  $days_until_appt = $appt->diff($today)->d;

// tercera forma
$fecha1 = date($fecha_actual);
$fecha2 = new Date($fecha_db);
echo  $fechaF = $fecha->diff($fecha2);
```

Comment: que error te estaria tirando.. porque salvo que no sean fechas validas deberia funcionar.. o no estoy viendo algo..

Comment: no me muestra nada me muestra cero o  se queda en blanco

Comment: Los datos de la fecha los trae de una base de datos.

Comment: si uno lo tomo de la base de datos y lo comparo con la actual para que me los dias que han transcurrido desde entonces pero me salen los dias aparece cero o en blanco

Comment: el primero tira 0 dias? podrias hacer un echo de lo que viene y lo que le pasas en cada paso, para ver que no sea un error de datos?

Answer (score 1):

Podes hacer una consulta SQL a la base de datos utilizando las funciones `DATEDIFF` (devuelve la diferencia de días entre dos fechas) y `CURDATE` (devuelve la fecha actual).

```
// Diferencia de días entre la fecha de la tabla y la fecha actual
SELECT DATEDIFF( CURDATE(), fecha ) AS Dias FROM tabla;

 __________
| Dias     |
|----------|
| 7        |
|__________|
```

Comment: entonces hago la consulta y donde tu tienes la fecha en numero yo pongo el campo de la tabla que es fecha para que lo compare?

Comment: @json Si, podes pasarle como argumento el campo de una tabla, una fecha fija o funciones como curdate.

Comment: muy bien lo pruebo

Answer (score 1):

Puedes probar convirtiendo las fechas a timestamp, restándolas y formateandolas posteriormente.

```
$fecha1 = strtotime($fecha1);
$fecha2 = strtotime($fecha2);

$res = $fecha2 - $fecha1;

$dias = date('d', $res);
```

Documentación de PHP:

[String to time](http://php.net/manual/es/function.strtotime.php)

[Date](http://php.net/manual/es/function.date.php)